# get array position in string array when value = 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a column that contain a binary string as this

`11110010`

i need to return position in another cell if found `1`

like this

`12347`

i try to use index and match function but it's doesn't work problaly

Comment: You should post the code what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in a module on your worksheet:

```
Function GetInstances(MyString As String, FindChar As String)
Dim X As Long, MyResult As String
MyResult = ""
For X = 1 To Len(MyString)
    If Mid(MyString, X, 1) = FindChar Then MyResult = MyResult & X
Next
GetInstances = MyResult
End Function
```

In Cell A1: `11110010`

In Cell B1 I used the new formula like so: `=GetInstances(A1,1)`

The result it gave me was `12347`

A1 contains the string to evaluate and the 1 in there is the number to find.

Answer (score 1):

**`InStr`** method can shown the position of a character but index start from **1**.

So, in `1234`, if we find `1`, it will return **1**. One thing is that, it will shown for the first matches.

I tested about it as:

```
MsgBox InStr("1234", "1")
```

I give me **1** in message box. But, when I tried as follow:

```
MsgBox InStr("12341", "1")
```

It don't give two message box for **position 1 and 5**. It just show message box for **position 1**.  If it is OK, try with this.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative function  that uses array for speed below:

```
Function StrOut(strIn As String)
Dim buff() As String
Dim lngCnt As Long
buff = Split(StrConv(strIn, vbUnicode), Chr$(0))
For lngCnt = 0 To UBound(buff) - 1
    StrOut = StrOut & (lngCnt + 1) * buff(lngCnt)
Next
StrOut = Replace(StrOut, "0", vbNullString)
End Function
```

*test code*

```
Sub Test()
MsgBox StrOut("11110010")
End Sub
```

Tinkered with a formula approach that I intended to try with `Evaluate`, got as far as
`=IF(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1)="1",ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),"X")`

which gives
`={1;2;3;4;"X";"X";7;"X"}`

but not progressed to completion yet.